# Magento Advance search issue with custom query

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've modified magento's Advance search **app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Mysql4** to use some custom conditions, because I wanted the search to use AND for certain attributes instead IN

But, it's not returning anything.
Here is the query I've modified:

```
if(in_array($value,$cSizeArray) && isset($_GET['condom_size'])){
    $select->where("{$tableAlias}.`value` IN(?)", $value);
}elseif(in_array($value,$lSizeArray) && isset($_GET['lubepack'])){
    $select->where("{$tableAlias}.`value` IN(?)", $value);
}else{
    if($tableAlias == 'ast_types' || $tableAlias== 'ast_lubetype'){
        $condition = "( ";  
        foreach($value as $v){
            $condition.=" {$tableAlias}.`value`= $v AND";
        }
        $condition = substr($condition,0,-3);           
        $condition .= " ) ";    
        $select->where($condition);
    }else{
        $select->where("{$tableAlias}.`value` IN(?)", $value);
    }
}
```

here is the query I got by using `echo $select`:

```
 `SELECT DISTINCT  `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(`price_index`.`tier_price`, LEAST(`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`), `price_index`.`min_price`) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='3' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `ast_types` ON e.entity_id=ast_types.entity_id AND ast_types.attribute_id=150 AND ast_types.store_id=3
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `ast_condom_size` ON e.entity_id=ast_condom_size.entity_id AND ast_condom_size.attribute_id=151 AND ast_condom_size.store_id=3 WHERE ((  ast_types.value= 131  AND ast_types.value= 135 ) ) AND (ast_condom_size.`value` IN('141', '140'))`
```

New Modified Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(`price_index`.`tier_price`, LEAST(`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`), `price_index`.`min_price`) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='3' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `ast_types` ON e.entity_id=ast_types.entity_id AND ast_types.attribute_id=150 AND ast_types.store_id=3
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `ast_condom_size` ON e.entity_id=ast_condom_size.entity_id AND ast_condom_size.attribute_id=151 AND ast_condom_size.store_id=3 WHERE ((  ast_types.`value`= 135 OR ast_types.`value`= 132 OR ast_types.`value`= 131  ) ) AND (ast_condom_size.`value` IN('141', '140')) GROUP BY sku HAVING COUNT(*)=3
```

Any idea on what may be wrong with approach...

Comment: You should take a look at resulting SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE ((  ast_types.value= 131  AND ast_types.value= 135 ) )
```

You are requiring a value to be 131 and 135 at the same time. This will never be true, so your result set will be empty.

Comment: yes, i figured it out, now i am trying to add `GROUP BY sku HAVING COUNT(*)=?` to the query, but, not sure, where to appened it

Comment: I added the above condition to the query, when I run the query, it returns the matching record, but, still search display incorrect records...

Comment: is it possible to get all attributes associated with a product? like we do `$_product->getAttributeSetId()` to get the attribute set id ?